# Как получить значение элемента XML В SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
<zap>
    <IDDT>ОН2</IDDT>
    <DTNAME>ТЕКСТ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ2</DTNAME>
    <DATEBEG>26.12.2013</DATEBEG>
    <DATEEND>31.12.2017</DATEEND>
  </zap>
  <zap>
    <IDDT>ОН3</IDDT>
    <DTNAME>ТЕКСТ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ</DTNAME>
    <DATEBEG>26.12.2013</DATEBEG>
    <DATEEND>31.12.2017</DATEEND>
  </zap>
```

Как во временную таблицу вставить значения из IDDT?

Comment: во первых это не атрибут а тэг, во вторых что это у вас, переменная, поле таблицы, или пример двух строк из таблицы?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то в таком духе:

```sql
DECLARE @x xml = N'<zap>
    <IDDT>ОН2</IDDT>
    <DTNAME>ТЕКСТ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ2</DTNAME>
    <DATEBEG>26.12.2013</DATEBEG>
    <DATEEND>31.12.2017</DATEEND>
  </zap>
  <zap>
    <IDDT>ОН3</IDDT>
    <DTNAME>ТЕКСТ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ</DTNAME>
    <DATEBEG>26.12.2013</DATEBEG>
    <DATEEND>31.12.2017</DATEEND>
  </zap>';

SELECT t.x.value('IDDT[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS iddt INTO #t FROM @x.nodes('/zap') AS t(x) 

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Результат:

```
iddt
----------
ОН2
ОН3
```